# How do I get iOS 16 for Simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I go to the simulator component download page in my Xcode app, I only see iOS through 15 listed. How do I get iOS 16 for Simulator?

---

Xcode 13.2.1 
macOS 11.6.8

Comment: Xcode 14 update

Answer (score 9):

Go to Xcode > Pref and Platforms tabs
Click the + Button and you should see the options.
You can see the supported and available version.
[image]

Comment: Note you may need to update your version of XCode or you will see "components" there instead with no iOS 16 simulators.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest macOS version and install Xcode 14.

Comment: So no way to do it on an old Mac?

Comment: Which Mac do you have? Monterey [has support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212551) for hardware going back quite a bit.